# Listing unreadable group files in Unix

Tags: unix, permissions, find

Is there a way I can list ordinary files that are unreadable by a group in Unix?

What would be the necessary code for that?

And can I do it without using the find command?

Comment: Files in one directory or across a file system?

Comment: There is a slight unclearness in your question: unreadable by any group (meaning perms without group read for anyone?) or just not readable by a specific group?

Answer (score 0):

It depends, which shell you are using. With `zsh` that following will do the trick:

```
ls -dl *(^A)
```

`ls -dl` prints a long (`l`) list without digging into directories (`d`). The more interesting part is the globbing part, where `A` would select only group-readable objects, combined with an inversion `^` this is what you want.